# How do I calculate percentage based on pixels for CSS conversion?

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS styles:

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: bentonsans-regular, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-image: url(../affiliate/amex/images/background.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-position: top left;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 150px;
  top: 50px;
}

#footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 150px;
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

And I need to change them from `px` to `%` but I have not idea in how to achieve this in accurate way. I've found [this](http://pxtoem.com/) which convert from `px` to `em` but this is not so helpful. site Could anyone point me to the right direction? Any ideas? Advices? Solutions?

Comment: I assume that `i` is the value I want to change right?

Comment: @shA.t so if I want to convert 100px to % will be `100/sum(100)*100`? ummm look suspicious :-\ what's the `sum`? a formula?

Comment: Oops! At first for a property like `height` sum all relatives `100 + 110 + ... = sum` then you can find the percentage for `100` like `100/sum*100` and for `110` is `110/sum*100` ;).

Comment: If you wanna change pixel to percent it is usually based of the width/height of the parent tag. What I do is in case I have to change it I open two Windows with the same HTML. Then with the inspector f12 in the browser keep one in pixel and change the other to %. Then just find which % make the tag place in the same position and done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It actually depends on the context where your elements live.
Always remember the simple formula **target / context**

I don't think you will find a converter since as I said, it depends on the context.

For example: to convert to percentage a 300px  inside a 1000px  container you would do

> 300/1000 = 0.3 which is 30%

If the 300px  has a padding of 10px and you want to convert it, do apply the formula considering the 300px  as your container (context). So

> 10/300 = 0.0333333333 which is 3.3333333% (keep the decimals)

For the font sizes, if you set the  font-size to 100%, that will refer to 100% of the default font size of the browser, which is most probably 16px for the major browsers. 
For an accurate reading on font-size check this: [The font-size CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-size)

Answer (score 2):

You can freely mention percentage for width, but better give "px" or "em" for height.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: bentonsans-regular, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-image: url(../affiliate/amex/images/background.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-position: top left;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
 width : 90% ;
  height: 100px;
max-width : 600px ;
left: 10%;
right : 10% ;
  top: 50px;
  background: gray ;

}

#footer {
  position: fixed;
 width : 90% ;
  height: 100px;
max-width : 600px ;
left: 10%;
right : 10% ;
  bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  background: gray ;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  header
</div>

<div id="footer" >
  footer
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, there was little bit mistake, if you give " width : 90% ;" (to header or footer), left and right margins should below 10% ( like left: 5%; right : 5% ;). not each 10%. (i mean do not exceed total amount to 100% )